# JQuery Each Function Give Style Dependant On List Level - Resolved just needs explaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

### List Example;

- Inbox

  - Sub-Folder 1
  - Sub-Folder 2
  - Sub-Folder 3

    - Sub-Folder 1

      - Sub-Folder 1
      - Sub-Folder 2
    - Sub-Folder 2
  - Sub-Folder 4
  - Sub-Folder 5
- Important
- Sent
- Draft
- Trash
- Promotions
- News

### List Example Source

```
<ul class="inbox-nav" id="inbox-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Inbox">
            <div class="Arrow"></div> Inbox
            <span class="badge badge-success">3</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_3">Sub-Folder 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_4">Sub-Folder 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_5">Sub-Folder 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="important" data-title="Inbox"> Important </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="sent" data-title="Sent"> Sent </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="draft" data-title="Draft"> Draft
            <span class="badge badge-danger">8</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="sbold uppercase" data-title="Trash"> Trash
            <span class="badge badge-info">23</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Promotions"> Promotions
            <span class="badge badge-warning">2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="News"> News </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Question

On this list, the user can create as many sub-folders as they wish. I need to loop through this list and create a `<select><option...` drop down list showing this list.

```
var listItems = $(".inbox-nav").find("li");
$('.foo').prepend($(listItems).html());
```

I know I can duplicate my list however for each li .text() I need to translate to `<option>Text Value</option>` and furthermore each tier I need to add the class `'tier' + Tier_Value` so my example code would turn out to look like;

```
<select>
  <option>Sub-Folder 1</option>
  <option>Sub-Folder 2</option>
  <option>Sub-Folder 3</option>
  <option class="tier1">Sub-Folder 1</option>
  <option class="tier2">Sub-Folder 1</option>
  <option class="tier2">Sub-Folder 2</option>
  <option class="tier1">Sub-Folder 2</option>
  <option>Sub-Folder 4</option>
  <option>Sub-Folder 5</option>
  ...
</select>
```

### My Best Attempt So Far:

```js
var sel = $('<select />');
$('.Alpha').prepend('<select />');
$('.inbox-nav li').each( function( index ) {
  if(!$(this).children("ul").length) {
    $('.Alpha select').append('<option>' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="inbox-nav" id="inbox-nav" style="display:none;">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Inbox">
            <div class="Arrow"></div> Inbox
            <span class="badge badge-success">3</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_3">Sub-Folder 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_4">Sub-Folder 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_5">Sub-Folder 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="important" data-title="Inbox"> Important </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="sent" data-title="Sent"> Sent </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="draft" data-title="Draft"> Draft
            <span class="badge badge-danger">8</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="sbold uppercase" data-title="Trash"> Trash
            <span class="badge badge-info">23</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Promotions"> Promotions
            <span class="badge badge-warning">2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="News"> News </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="Alpha"></div>
```

### UPDATE I

Previously prior this update, the drop down was showing certain `<li></li>` `.text()` values from all their `.children()` however I've just figured out an if statement to resolve this; `if(!$(this).children("ul").length) {`

### UPDATE II

I have managed to find the right resources to answer my own question as such however as I do not understand how it works, I'm not posting an answer at the moment but feel free to take a look at the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/703ydrLa/) and add a bit of explaining. (Ignore the part where it ignores the span sext as I do understand this part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use a recursive function to process each list and then its sub-lists.

```js
$(function() {
 var options = processList($('#inbox-nav'), 0); // Compile options starting at #inbox-nav
  $('.Alpha').html('<select>' + options + '</select>'); // Create and add select box
  
  function processList(list, level) { // Recursive function
    var options = '';
    list.children('li').each(function() { // For each child li
      options += '<option' + (level ? ' class="tier' + level + '"' : '') + '>' +
        $(this).children('a').text() + '</option>'; // Add an option for this li
      var subList = $(this).children('ul'); // Find any embedded list
      if (subList.length) { // If there is a sub-list
        options += processList(subList, level + 1); // Compile options starting at that list, and on the next level
      }
    });
    return options; // Return the compile options
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="inbox-nav" id="inbox-nav" style="display:none;">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Inbox">
                <div class="Arrow"></div> Inbox
                <span class="badge badge-success">3</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_3">Sub-Folder 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_1">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_2">Sub-Folder 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_4">Sub-Folder 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Sub_5">Sub-Folder 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="important" data-title="Inbox"> Important </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="sent" data-title="Sent"> Sent </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="draft" data-title="Draft"> Draft
                <span class="badge badge-danger">8</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="sbold uppercase" data-title="Trash"> Trash
                <span class="badge badge-info">23</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="Promotions"> Promotions
                <span class="badge badge-warning">2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-type="inbox" data-title="News"> News </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="Alpha"></div>
```